# How can I get the id of the process that triggered a callback of registry filter driver?

Tags: windows, callback, registry, driver, hook

I am developping a registry filtering driver which monitors and block some operations on some registry keys.
Everything is working fine but I would like also to get the id of the process that triggered the callback, I mean the process that tried to perform the registry operation.
Is there a way I can do that?

From the callback I have the NotifyClass, which gave me the pointer to the object key.
By using ObOpenObjectByPointer, I also could get the HANDLE to the key being operated on.

I tried to use ObReferenceObjectByHandle and get a PEPROCESS which I can use in PsGetProcessId, but I guess it is not right because it did not give the pid.

I also made a lot of research but could not find that much helpfull answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nc-wdm-ex_callback_function):

> A *RegistryCallback* executes at IRQL = PASSIVE_LEVEL and in the context of the thread that is performing the registry operation.

Thus you can use `PsGetCurrentProcessId()` to obtain the process ID.